# how do I find two parent directories up in perl?

Tags: perl, path

I have a path: `/path/to/here/file.txt`.

I want to get `/path/to/`

Using

```
 my ($file, $dir) = fileparse($fullPath);
```

I can get `file.txt` and `/path/to/here/`

How do I get just `/path/to/`?

Comment: You should use modules as in the two answers below, by all means and for a number of reasons.  But just btw, you do realize that you can just parse the string (with regex or split) as well, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Path::Class qw( file );

say file("/path/to/here/file.txt")->dir->parent;
```

Note that this does not perform any file-system checks, so it will return `/path/to` even if `/path/to` is a symbolic link and thus not truly the parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny):

```bash
$ perl -MPath::Tiny -e 'CORE::say path($ARGV[0])->parent->parent' /path/to/here/file.txt
```

This does not perform any file system checks either. Doing it using only [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) tends to get tedious. I am not positive the following works:

```bash
$ perl -MFile::Spec::Functions=splitpath,catpath,catdir,splitdir -e \
 '($v, $d) = splitpath($ARGV[0]); @d = splitdir $d; splice @d, -2;  \
 CORE::say catpath($v, catdir (@d))' /path/to/here/file.txt
```